# How to remove this adhesive, is it a hard job?

Tags: adhesive

[image]

Here is a pic of some adhesive under my vinyl tiles.  The glue is brown, thick and strong.  I’m thinking to just cover it if the removal is a lot of work.

How can I move it diy and is it a hard job?

Comment: Hard as in possible but difficult or hard as in lots of work? But if you don’t like the smell...

Comment: On my concrete laundry floor I used chemicals, it was a lot of work, and then put down porcelain tiles.  I wanted the mastic to have something to hold on to.  On my kitchen floor, I didn't want the chemicals seeping into the underpayment so I put down rosin paper and put down floating luxury tiles on top of that.  Both jobs turned out well.

Answer (score 1):

It’s funny we have had several questions with these tiles lately, the adhesive is asphalt based or it appears to be the same as I have seen many times and it will clean up with mineral spirits but takes a fair amount of work.

Since those tiles are usually asbestos filled for the last 20 years I have recommend removing loose ones filling the void and overlaying.

I have put down epoxy /pebble , carpet and regular tile and vinyl floor coverings over this type of tile, it looks like you are having better luck at removing the tiles so maybe that stuff is drying out, but use caution as the tiles did normally contain asbestos.

So yes it is a lot of work to clean it up and leaving the tiles in place may be a better plan unless they are loose , normally Around the edge I find a few loose ones. 
I use self leveling compound to fill the void it has stayed in place well even where vinyl flooring was glued over the top and the epoxy pebble (yes it can be done indoors and looks much better than a heavily cracked 1920’s floor).

Comment: Are you saying not to move the tiles because it may release asbestos, does pushing or snapping them out cause asbestos to be released? if so you seem to suggest leveling the floor out with replacement tiles then covering over it.  Problem here is these tiles have gaps in them which according to this answer cannot really be filled https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/191304/why-do-installers-leave-a-gap-between-vinyl-tiles and so the lines will show through the new flooring.  Therefore isn't it best to remove the tiles, or what would you suggest.  Many thanks.

Comment: I am saying that scratching, chipping breaking the tiles will release asbestos on the ones that have it. mostly anything like this pre 1980.  I am suggesting to fill any voids with a self leveling compound normally called “ self leveling cement “ if you are concerned the gaps between tiles will show through on your new flooring I would use “spackle” or a hot mud for Sheetrock , hot mud sets up and will easily fill the cracks but not the large missing tile areas. Not trying to freak you out on the asbestos as I have probably reworked +  one hundred floors like this but there are risks.

Comment: Note I strongly disagree that there is nothing that can be done, there is special vinyl seam hell that is made just for that but it is expensive and made to match the vinyl being installed, since you are overlaying go cheap and get a bag of 90 or 120 minute hot mud mix it up and fill the gaps it will set up and the cracks are gone. Don’t use standard joint compound it will not set , well it could set but next winter if the concrete wicks moisture the standard joint compound will become fluid , hot mud or quick setting joint compound will set and moisture won’t affect it.