# Quick and temp way to cover this floor?

Tags: flooring

[image]

The glue in the pic is making me sick and I just want to temporarily cover it until I decide whether I will replace the whole floor etc.

I have some vinyl sheet lying around so I'd like to make use of it if possible. I thought I’ll just cut it to fit and then go around it with silicone(to prevent current adhesive or vinyl backing smell from coming out).

Will this work or what is the minimum I will need to do in order to temporsrily but somewhat effectively cover this beating in mind the edges will meet vinyl tiles.

Perhaps the new sheet needs to be cut, glued down and then something around to seal the underneath in.  Will caulk do it to go around?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if you would glue it down if you are only having it as a temporary, you can cut it and lay it and it will do the job though.

You can silicone the edges and it will leave a nice finish and it is quite easily removed when you decide something permanent.

Comment: In the answer to this question https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/191304/why-do-installers-leave-a-gap-between-vinyl-tiles  where the tiles have gaps between them, the answer said nothing will hold down therefore since the edges are the same it would follow silicone would not hold the vinyl sheet down?  Do you disagree with linked answer?  Thanks.

Comment: The silicone is just to tidy it up and seal it at the sides, It won't hold it down. That could be the case it will not sit flat if you have gaps. The floor needs to nice and flat and even otherwise it will cause the vinyl to deform to the uneven shape of the floor. I have removed a few old vinyl floors and they wasn't stuck down but it was a nice even surface.